# Difference between Delphi 64-bit Debug and Release configurations?

Tags: delphi, 32bit-64bit

I use the following code to get my app’s EXE version. The code is in the FormCreate:

```
procedure Tform1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  vMajor, vMinor, vRelease, vBuild: DWord;
  size, len: longword;
  handle: DWord;
  buffer: pchar;
  pinfo: ^VS_FIXEDFILEINFO;
begin

  try
    size := GetFileVersionInfoSize(Pointer(Application.ExeName), handle);
    if size > 0 then begin
      GetMem(buffer, size);
      if GetFileVersionInfo(Pointer(Application.ExeName), 0, size, buffer)
      then
        if VerQueryValue(buffer, '\', pointer(pinfo), len) then begin
          VMajor   := HiWord(pinfo.dwFileVersionMS);
          VMinor   := LoWord(pinfo.dwFileVersionMS);
          VRelease := HiWord(pinfo.dwFileVersionLS);
          VBuild   := LoWord(pinfo.dwFileVersionLS);
        end;
    end;
  finally
    FreeMem(buffer);
  end;
…
```

The code works as expected in 32-bit Debug and Release configurations as well as in 64-bit Debug.  It returns the current version which is 2022.4.112.891.

However, in 64-bit Release configuration, the VRelease and VBuild are incorrect and the code returns 2022.4.8614.28017.

The GetFileVersionInfoSize for 32-bit Release and 64-bit release is the same, which I would expect.

What is the difference between 64-bit Debug and Release configurations that would cause the call to fail?

Comment: Version information can be adjusted separately for each build configuration. You probably have different configured version for 64-bit release and debug builds.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to load the resource using hinstance rather than a file based api?

Answer (score 0):

Dalija is correct.  I had been focusing on the Compiler and Linker settings... and did not look at the Version, Build Number options that was set to "Auto increment Build Numbers" for the 64-Bit Release and it should be set to "Do Not Change Build numbers".  Time to call it a day!

Thanks!